# History of thought experiments

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, history, thought-experiment

I am writing a little article about thought experiments through the history of physics (university level); more specifically, from the times of Thales of Miletus (~ ancient Greeks) to our day. 
I want to cover as many as possible of them, and not just stick to the most famous ones as those of Einstein (for example).
I should point out that I have already searched on the internet (including this site), and already got a good number of them; but I want to be sure I have not overlooked any interesting thought experiment.

So my question is, does anybody know about any thought experiments that are not commonly known (even for a physics grad student with access to Google)? 
Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Ok, main question could be too broad so I'll be more precise:

Do you know about any thought experiments (in physics) dated from before those of Galileo?

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking for an open-ended list of examples with no single correct answer, which is off-topic as *too broad* here.

Comment: Atomistic theory from the old Greeks. Amazing that they came to the conclusion that  a smallest piece of something has to exist. You bring me to an idea. Wouldn't it be more interesting to investigate which thought experiments are grandiosely failed?